# Submitting HTML and CSS coordinates and values with jQuery on a user submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a web app where users an drag and drop text on an image.  Ideally, I would like my uses to be able to save their image with the overlayed text.  To do this I plan to use PIL (Python Imaging Library) to recreate the picture in the backend.

On an HTML form submit I would like to send the values of the coordinates of the four corners of an img, the coordinates of any overlayed text, along with their hex color and font-size.

Is it possible to capture all of this with jQuery or JavaScript?

In this JS Fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/booyaa/YvJhE/ the text is draggable.  Say the user moves the text over the image.  In order to recreate the image (with the text that the user dragged) i would need to coordinates of where the text was dragged to.  Is it possible to X Y coordinates for an HTML element with jQuery?

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
<img src="http://imgur.com/JS1HXFw.jpg">

$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
```

---

```
$("#capture").click(
    function(event) {
        var photoCoords = $("img").position();
    })
```

I am getting undefined for var photoCoords in console. any idea why?

Comment: Could you provide some example code or even an jsfiddle? It is pretty hard to guess what you'd need to do in your specific setup with so little information.

Comment: updated with jsfiddle

Comment: You need to encase the selector in quotes, e.g. ``"img"``

Comment: now I am getting undefined when i type var photoCoords in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use

```
 $(selector).offset();
```

or

```
 $(selector).position();
```

to get the coordinates of an element. While `offset` gives you the coordinates relative to the element, `position` gives you the coordinates relative to the element's offset parent.

In the example you provided both will return exactly the same as the offset parent for `#draggable` in fact is the body, which is positioned at 0,0 relative to your document.

In your use case as I understood it you would probably want to get both the `#draggable`'s and the image's `offset` and pass it along to the server. By comparison of both elements' coordinates (`top` and `left`) you can easily determine their position relative to each other and should have everything to create the composed image in question.

- [jQuery docs on `position`](https://api.jquery.com/position/)
- [jQuery docs on `offset`](https://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Comment: edited the above with a new question on the selector

Comment: Could you post a new question as an actual new question? Anyway: You'd probably want to set an id (<img id="foo" src="..." />) on your image and select it like this `$('#foo')`. `$('img')` will give you all images in the DOM, and `$(img)` will try to resolve the variable `img` which just is not defined.